# Python String Reversal

Tags: python, string

This exercise involves a codeacademy problem to write a function which takes a string as an input and outputs the string in reverse, I've found solutions as to how to do it online, I'm just confused as to why mine doesnt work:

```
def reverse(c):
    empty=[]
    stringsize= len(c)

    for x in range(stringsize):
        empty[x]=c[stringsize-x]

    return empty
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't much of an error description. Maybe actually _look_ at the error you're getting?

Comment: You will get an `IndexError` because `empty` list you have does not have anything in it, it is basically empty. You should `append` to it. Check python docs.

Comment: incidentally, you could use the `reversed` function to reverse your string. something like this: `"".join(list(reversed("foo")))`, though there may exist even simpler solutions. I'm calling `list()` because `reversed` returns a "reversed object", which I then need to turn back into a string.

Comment: @tayfun: no, you'll get an `IndexError` because `c[stringsize]` is out of bounds; the last index is `c[stringsize - 1]`.

Comment: @m01: `str.join()` calls list on the `reversed()` iterator for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start at indexing your string from `-1` through to `-stringsize`, and use `empty.append()` to add values:

```
for x in range(stringsize):
    empty.append(c[stringsize - x - 1])
```

Python indexing starts at 0, making `stringsize - 1` the last index. Because `empty` is an empty list, you cannot index into it. Using the `list.append()` method adds new values at the end instead.

You don't really *need* the `stringsize` reference there, because negative indices automatically are subtracted from the length for you:

```
for x in range(len(c)):
    empty.append(c[-x-1])
```

Since this is supposed to return a string, not a list, you need to join the characters again at the end:

```
return ''.join(empty)
```

The easiest way to reverse a list is to use a negative slice stride:

```
def reverse(c):
    return c[::-1]
```

Comment: … or even better, allocate `empty` beforehand: `empty = [None] * len(stringsize)` ;-)

Comment: @Alfe: nah, not better.

Comment: I feel it is closer to what OP tried in the first place, so, less change to his idea.  He asked for reasoning why his didn't work, not for a faster solution.

Comment: @Alfe: it doesn't work because `empty` is empty. So there are two alternative solutions; prepopulate or `list.append()`. The latter is easier to explain.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of the meaning of the name, right.  But taking this into account, `empty.append(…)` seems to be a sin as well.

Comment: (Just make that clear, no downvote from me of course.  So, yeah, downvoter, explain yourself.)

Comment: @Alfe: Didn't think it was you. :-) I have received a number of unexplained downvotes lately, I actually think my favourite grumpy perma-suspended user is back with another ban-bypass account.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really useful! Python is great but can be so confusing!

Answer (score 2):

**One solution :**

```
def reverse(c):
    empty=[]
    stringsize= len(c)
    for x in range(stringsize):
        empty.append(c[-(x+1)])
    return ''.join(empty)

print reverse('string')
```

**Another**:

```
    def reverse(c):
    empty=[]
    stringsize= len(c)
    for x in range(stringsize):
        empty.append(c[stringsize - (x+1)])
    return ''.join(empty)

print reverse('string')
```

**Using recursion:**

```
    def reverse(string,start,stop):
    if start < stop - 1:
        string[start],string[stop - 1] = string[stop - 1],string[start]
        reverse(string,start+1, stop-1)
    return ''.join(string)

print reverse(list('string'), 0, len('string'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python a string is an `iterable` so iterable functions can be used with it. For example `reversed` function:

```
>>> "".join(reversed("123"))
'321'
```

Comment: He asked not for a reverter but for a reason why his code didn't work.

Comment: @Alfe: I know, I saw that other answers provided a good explanation so I added an alternative. But yeah, thank you for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

The least changes necessary to make your code run seem to be:

```
def reverse(c):
    stringsize= len(c)
    empty=[None] * stringsize

    for x in range(stringsize):
        empty[x]=c[stringsize-x-1]

    return empty
```

But you should reconsider your name `empty` (as Martijn pointed out) because that thing isn't *empty* (at least in the end), so the name is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The classic answer to this problem is to use a slice with a negative step to get what you want:

```
def reverse(c):
    return c[::-1]
```

...but maybe that's not allowed for you?

Comment: The OP already found other methods and just wanted to know why their own solution didn't work. You are not answering that question here.